# Are there More Hard Objects or Soft Objects

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, counting

*Tangentially inspired by the opening to the What-If book.*

The input is a rectangle of spaces as a string, list of string, etc., with objects made of `#`'s inside:

```
########          
#      #          
########          

   ###        ####
   ###        ####
   ###
```

The objects will always be non-intersecting, non-touching, rectangles. A soft object is defined as an object that isn't filled up with `#`'s in the middle and is only a border, a hard object is one that is filled up. An object with width or height `<=2` is considered hard. All objects are either hard or soft.

If there are more hard objects in the input, output `"Hard"`, if more soft, output `"Soft"`, if they are equal, output `"Equal"`.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

## Test Cases

**These cases aren't full inputs, but rather what each object should be characterized as.** The actual input will be like the ascii-art at the top of the question.

### Hard

```
#

####

##
##

##########
##########
##########
```

### Soft

```
###
# #
###

###################
#                 #
#                 #
#                 #
###################

####
#  #
#  #
#  #
#  #
#  #
#  #
#  #
####
```

### Actual Test Cases

```
########          
#      #          
########          

   ###        ####
   ###        ####
   ###             

Hard

###                
###                
###                

###################
#                 #
#                 #
#                 #
###################

Equal

   ######    
   #    #    
   ######    
          ###
   ##  #  # #
          ###


 ########    
 #      #    
 ########  

Soft
```

Comment: Are the outputs strict, or can any 3 unambiguous outputs be used (such as H/S/E or -1/0/1)?

Comment: @trichoplax they are strict

Comment: [Meta answer on cumbersome I/O formats](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/20283) (not to say you can't do what you choose, but just to give a place for people to express a more fine grained opinion if they wish).

Comment: @DLosc sure that's fine, adding.

Comment: @LuisMendo no, adding.

Comment: I assume that by "more hard objects" you mean the *number* (count) of hard objects, not (for example) the area of hard objects...

Comment: Perhaps add a couple of actual test cases?

Comment: Are all objects guaranteed to be either hard or soft?

Comment: @Maltysen I've added two examples in my answer. Feel free to use include them as test cases

Comment: Do we have to take the input as a single strings or can we take it as an array of rows?

Comment: @user2357112 yes, clarifying.

Comment: @Dennis either is fine: "string, list of string"

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>105</s> <s>104</s> <s>58</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

*Thanks to @Neil for a suggestion that allowed me to remove 46 bytes!*

```
2\TTYaEq4:HeqgEqZ+K/Zot0>+ss'Soft Hard Equal'Ybw)
```

Input is a 2D char array, with rows separated by `;`. The example in the challenge is

```
['########          ';'#      #          ';'########          ';'                  ';'   ###        ####';'   ###        ####';'   ###            ']
```

Here's another example:

```
['###                ';'###                ';'###                ';'                   ';'###################';'#                 #';'#                 #';'#                 #';'###################']
```

This corresponds to

```
###                
###                
###                

###################
#                 #
#                 #
#                 #
###################
```

and thus should give `'Equal'`.

As a third example, corresponding to `'Soft'`,

```
['   ######    ';'   #    #    ';'   ######    ';'          ###';'   ##  #  # #';'          ###';'             ';'             ';' ########    ';' #      #    ';' ########    ']
```

that is,

```
   ######    
   #    #    
   ######    
          ###
   ##  #  # #
          ###


 ########    
 #      #    
 ########
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MlxUVFlhRXE0OkhlcWdFcVorSy9ab3QwPitzcydTb2Z0IEhhcmQgRXF1YWwnWWJ3KQ&input=WycjIyMjIyMjIyAgICAgICAgICAnOycjICAgICAgIyAgICAgICAgICAnOycjIyMjIyMjIyAgICAgICAgICAnOycgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAnOycgICAjIyMgICAgICAgICMjIyMnOycgICAjIyMgICAgICAgICMjIyMnOycgICAjIyMgICAgICAgICAgICAnXQ)

#### Explanation

This uses 2D convolution to detect shapes. The input is converted to a 2D array with `1` indicating `#` and `-1` for space; and is padded with a frame of `-1` values. This assures that shapes at the edge of the original field are also detected.

A *soft object* is detected by the mask

```
 1   1
 1  -1
```

which corresponds to the object's upper-left corner with one empty interior point. Note that the convolution inverts the mask, so it is defined as `[-1 1; 1 1]` in the code. The number *S* of positions in which the convolution equals `4` is the total number of soft objects.

An *object* (soft or hard) is detected by the mask

```
-1  -1
-1   1
```

which correponds to the object's upper-left corner together with some empty exterior points. This mask is the negated version of the previous one, so the previous convolution result can be reused. Specifically, the number *T* of positions in which that result equals `-4` is the total number of objects.

The number *H* of hard objects is *T*−*S*. The output string is determined by the sign of *S*−*H* = 2**S*−*T*.

```
2\                 % Input. Modulo 2: '#' gives 1, ' ' gives 0
TTYa               % Add a frame of zeros
Eq                 % Convert 0 to -1
4:HeqgEq           % Generate mask [-1 1; 1 1], for soft objects
Z+                 % 2D convolution, preserving size
K/Zo               % Divide by 4 and round towards 0. Gives 1 or -1 for 4 or -4
t0>                % Duplicate. 1 for positive entries (soft objects), 0 otherwise
+                  % Add. This corresponds to the factor 2 that multiplies number S
ss                 % Sum of 2D array. Gives 2*S-T
'Soft Hard Equal'  % Push this string
Yb                 % Split by spaces. Gives cell array
w)                 % Swap. Apply (modular) index to select one string
```

Comment: So, I have no idea what a convolution is, but couldn't you just count all the objects (by finding e.g. the top left corner) and comparing with twice the number of soft objects?

Comment: @Neil that looks very promising, thanks! That way I could reduce from 5 to 2 convolutions. (A convolution is essentially seeing if a specific pattern matches at some position). I'll try it later

Comment: ... or even just 1 convolution! Thanks a lot! 46 bytes off:-) @Neil

Comment: It was almost on par with JS ... @Neil which side are you on ;-)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>123</s> <s>121</s> 118 bytes

```js
s=>s.replace(/#+/g,(m,i)=>s[i+l]>" "?0:n+=!m[1]|s[i-l+1]==s[i-l]||-1,n=l=~s.search`
|$`)|n>l?"Hard":n<l?"Soft":"Equal"
```

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @edc65!*

Takes input as a multiline string padded with spaces to form a grid.

### Explanation / Test

<s>Very close to MATL length!</s> Basically, it searches for the top line of `#`s of each object, and if the length of the top line is less than 2 or the first 2 characters below the top line are the same, it is hard, otherwise soft.

```js
var solution =

s=>
  s.replace(/#+/g,(m,i)=>        // for each run of consecutive # characters
    s[i+l]>" "?                  // if the position above the match contains a #
      0                          // do nothing (this object has already been counted)
    :n+=                         // add 1 to the counter (hard) if
      !m[1]                      // the match is only 1 # wide
      |s[i-l+1]==s[i-l]          // or the characters below are the same
      ||-1,                      // else decrement the counter (soft)
    n=                           // n = counter, hard objects increase n, soft decrease
    l=~s.search`\n|$`            // l = (negative) line length
  )
  |n>l?"Hard":n<l?"Soft":"Equal" // return the result string

// Test
document.write("<pre>" + [`

########          
#      #          
########          
                  
   ###        ####
   ###        ####
   ###            

`,`

###                
###                
###                
                   
###################
#                 #
#                 #
#                 #
###################

`,`

   ######    
   #    #    
   ######    
          ###
   ##  #  # #
          ###
             
             
 ########    
 #      #    
 ########    

`,`

########          
#      #          
########          
                  
   ###        ####
   # #        ####
   ###            

`,`

########          
#      #          
########          
                  
   ###  ###   ####
   ###  # #   ####
   ###  ###       

`,`

#

`,`

##

`,`

#
#

`,`

###
# #
###

`].map((test) => solution(test.slice(2, -2))).join("\n")
)
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with single-line input; `###` returns `Equal`.

Comment: @Dennis You're right. It seems that for single line input my previous code relied on the bug I fixed. Fixed now.

Comment: IMHO `~g.search(/$/m)` is slightly more readable than `~g.search\`\n\`||-1`.

Comment: @Neil True. There was a bug so I hastily tacked `||-1` on to fix it, but your suggestion made me realise that adding `|$` to the regex would save 2 bytes anyway. Thanks!

Comment: You could use just 1 counter `n=l=...` `n>l?...:n<l?...:...`

Comment: ... and of course increment or decrement n

Comment: @edc65 Great idea, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, <s>50</s> <s>49</s> <s>46</s> <s>43</s> <s>38</s> <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
Ḥ+ḊZ
>⁶ÇÇFµċ7_ċ4$Ṡị“¤Ỵf“¢*ɦ“¡⁺ƒ»
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bikK-G4iloKPuKBtsOHw4dGwrXEizdfxIs0JOG5oOG7i-KAnMKk4bu0ZuKAnMKiKsmm4oCcwqHigbrGksK7&input=&args=WycjIyMjIyMjIyAgICAgICAgICAnLCAnIyAgICAgICMgICAgICAgICAgJywgJyMjIyMjIyMjICAgICAgICAgICcsICcgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAnLCAnICAgIyMjICAgICAgICAjIyMjJywgJyAgICMjIyAgICAgICAgIyMjIycsICcgICAjIyMgICAgICAgICAgICAnXQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bikK-G4iloKPuKBtsOHw4dGwrXEizdfxIs0JOG5oOG7i-KAnMKk4bu0ZuKAnMKiKsmm4oCcwqHigbrGksK7CsOH4oKsauKBtw&input=&args=WwogWycjIyMjIyMjIyAgICAgICAgICAnLAogICcjICAgICAgIyAgICAgICAgICAnLAogICcjIyMjIyMjIyAgICAgICAgICAnLAogICcgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAnLAogICcgICAjIyMgICAgICAgICMjIyMnLAogICcgICAjIyMgICAgICAgICMjIyMnLAogICcgICAjIyMgICAgICAgICAgICAnXSwKCiBbJyMjIyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAnLAogICcjIyMgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJywKICAnIyMjICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICcsCiAgJyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAnLAogICcjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjJywKICAnIyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIycsCiAgJyMgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICMnLAogICcjICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAjJywKICAnIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyddLAoKIFsnICAgIyMjIyMjICAgICcsCiAgJyAgICMgICAgIyAgICAnLAogICcgICAjIyMjIyMgICAgJywKICAnICAgICAgICAgICMjIycsCiAgJyAgICMjICAjICAjICMnLAogICcgICAgICAgICAgIyMjJywKICAnICAgICAgICAgICAgICcsCiAgJyAgICAgICAgICAgICAnLAogICcgIyMjIyMjIyMgICAgJywKICAnICMgICAgICAjICAgICcsCiAgJyAjIyMjIyMjIyAgICAnXQpd).

#### Background

There are **16** different **2×2** patterns of blocks and spaces:

```
|  |  |  | #|  | #| #|# | #|# |# |##|# |##|##|##|
|  | #|# |  |##| #|# |  |##| #|# |  |##| #|# |##|
```

Of these, since two objects will never touch,

```
| #|# |
|# | #|
```

will never occur in the input, leaving us with **14** possible patterns.

Assigning   a value of **0** and `#` a value of **1**, we can encode a **2×2** pattern

```
|ab|
|cd|
```

as **2(2a + c) + (2b + d) = 4a + 2b + 2c + d**, leaving the following values for the **14** patterns.

```
|  |  |  | #|  | #|# | #|# |##|# |##|##|##|
|  | #|# |  |##| #|  |##|# |  |##| #|# |##|
  0  1  2  2  3  3  4  5  6  6  7  7  8  9
```

For partial **2×1**, **1×2** or **1×1** patterns at the lower and/or right border, we'll treat them as if the were padded with spaces, encoding them as **4a + 2b**, **4a + 2c** and **4a**, respectively.

This way, each object (soft or hard) will have exactly one **4** pattern (its lower right corner); each soft object will have exactly two **7** patterns (its lower left and its upper right corner).

Thus, subtracting the amount of **4** patterns from the number of **7** patterns encountered in the input will yield **(s + h) - 2s = h - s := d**, where **h** and **s** are the amount of hard and soft objects they form.

We print *Hard* if **d > 0**, *Soft* if **d < 0** and *Equal* if **d = 0**.

#### How it works

```
Ḥ+ḊZ                         Helper link. Input: M (n×m matrix)

Ḥ                            Unhalve; multiply all entries of M by 2.
  Ḋ                          Dequeue; remove the first row of M.
 +                           Perform vectorized addition.
                             This returns 2 * M[i] + M[i + 1] for each row M[i].
                             Since the M[n] is unpaired, + will not affect it,
                             as if M[n + 1] were a zero vector.
   Z                         Zip; transpose rows with columns.


>⁶ÇÇFµċ7_ċ4$Ṡị“¤Ỵf“¢*ɦ“¡⁺ƒ»  Main link. Input: G (character grid)

>⁶                           Compare each character with ' ', yielding 1 for '#'
                             and 0 for ' '.
  Ç                          Call the helper link.
                             This will compute (2a + c) for each pattern, which is
                             equal to (2b + d) for the pattern to its left.
   Ç                         This yields 2(2a + c) + (2b + d) for each pattern.
    F                        Flatten; collect all encoded patterns in a flat list.

     µ                       Begin a new, monadic link. Argument: A (list)
      ċ7                     Count the amount of 7's.
         ċ4$                 Count the amount of 4's.
        _                    Subtract the latter from the former.
            Ṡ                Yield the sign (1, -1 or 0) of the difference.
              “¤Ỵf“¢*ɦ“¡⁺ƒ»  Yield ['Hard', 'Soft', Equal'] by indexing into a
                             built-in dictionary.
             ị               Retrieve the string at the corresponding index.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, <s>99</s> <s>95</s> 93 bytes

```
~=t->2t'+[t[2:end,:];0t[1,:]]'
!x=("Hard","Equal","Soft")[sign(~~(x.>32)∩(4,7)-5.5|>sum)+2]
```

`!` expects a two-dimensional Char array as argument. [Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=fj10LT4ydCcrW3RbMjplbmQsOl07MHRbMSw6XV0nCiF4PSgiSGFyZCIsIkVxdWFsIiwiU29mdCIpW3NpZ24ofn4oeC4-MzIp4oipKDQsNyktNS41fD5zdW0pKzJdCgpmb3IgeCBpbiAoCgpbJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJwogJyMnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnIycgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJwogJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJwogJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJwogJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJwogJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJwogJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJ10sCgpbJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnCiAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcKICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJwogJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnCiAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycKICcjJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcjJwogJyMnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyMnCiAnIycgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnIycKICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJ10sCgpbJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnCiAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnIycgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyMnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcKICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJwogJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnCiAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcjJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcjJyAgJyAnICAnIycKICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJwogJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnCiAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcKICcgJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJwogJyAnICAnIycgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcjJyAgJyAnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnCiAnICcgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnIycgICcjJyAgJyMnICAnICcgICcgJyAgJyAnICAnICddCgopCiAgICBwcmludGxuKCF4KQplbmQ)

#### How it works

This uses almost exactly the same idea as [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78055), with one improvement:

Instead of counting the amount of **4**'s and **7**'s, we remove all other numbers, then subtract **5.5** to map **(4, 7)** to **(-1.5, 1.5)**. This way, the sign of the sum of the resulting differences determines the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

## TSQL, <s>328</s> 249 bytes

Declaring variables and test data:

```
DECLARE @l int = 20
DECLARE @ varchar(max)=''
SELECT @+=LEFT(x + replicate(' ', @l), @l)
FROM (values
(' xxxx'),
(' xxxx'),
(' xxxx'),
('x'),
(''),
('xxx'),
('x x  xxx'),
('xxx  x x'),
('     xxx    ')) x(x)
```

Code:

```
SELECT substring('Soft EqualHard',sign(sum(iif(substring(@,N,@l+2)like'xx'+replicate('_', @l-2)+'x ',-1,1)))*5+6,5)FROM(SELECT row_number()OVER(ORDER BY Type)N FROM sys.all_objects)x WHERE n<=len(@)AND' x'=substring(@,N-1,2)AND''=substring(@,N-@l,1)
```

Code deflated:

```
SELECT
  substring('Soft EqualHard',
    sign(sum(iif(substring(@,N,@l+2)like'xx'+replicate('_', @l-2)+'x ',-1,1)))*5+6,5)
FROM(SELECT row_number()OVER(ORDER BY Type)N FROM sys.all_objects)x
WHERE n<=len(@)AND' x'=substring(@,N-1,2)AND''=substring(@,N-@l,1)
```

Explaination:

Script is scanning the text for the pattern:

```
      space
space x
```

Each of those is the start of a box

For those positions, the script is then checking for the pattern, don't need to check for first x:

```
  x
x space
```

When that exists it is a soft object, otherwise it is a hard object.